# htaccess for symfony2 in shared hosting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony

i have a shared hosting. 
I want to see a example of .htaccess file in public_html folder to setup a symfony2 application(the entry point is web/app.php)
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/web/.htaccess - Also, without SSH access, working with Symfony is going to be painful

Answer (score 0):

The symfony standard edition already contains a [.htaccess](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/web/.htaccess) which you can use.

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: but this is the .htaccess inside web folder, i need a .htaccess to place in public_html directory, where the symfony2 project will be

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DirectoryIndex public_html/app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public_html/
    RewriteRule (.*) /public_html/$1
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /public_html/app.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Set it up on the root folder, one level above `public_html`.